# Syntax error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

**Problem**

I have a bit of code that keeps throwing an Syntax error but only in IE.
I ran the code in JSLint but it didn't help me understand the issue.

**JavaScript**

```
 $('#sub').click(function() {
items = my_arr.filter(i => i.percent && i.unit);
     console.log(items);
})
```

IE 11  (Error)

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: scripts.js, Line: 3346, Column: 26
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which error you're receiving?

Comment: arrow functions are new...check support for browser and version http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: In what version of IE? IE10 for instance don't support arrow functions and will throw syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this ES6 [Browser Compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Arrow notation is ES6 feature and not supported by IE.